# How to delete all rows where a where clause is met with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy

I would like to use a where clause that finds a certain columns, and if empty then delete the row.

My SQL where clause is; 
`SELECT UID2 FROM MY311CONTAINERS_2 WHERE SR_SN_2 <> ' ' AND SR_COLOR_2 <> ' ' AND SR_SIZE_2 <> ' ' AND SR_LOCATION2 <> ' '`

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
aContainerFC2 = 'fc'
fields = ("SR_SN_2", "SR_LOCATION_2", "Dist02", "SR_Color_2", "SR_Size_2")
whereClause = fields + " <>  ' ' "
updCurs = arcpy.UpdateCursor(aContainerFC2, whereClause)
for row in updCurs:
    if not row.getValue(field):
        updCurs.deleteRow(row)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Comment: what is the value of field? fields is defined but not field

Comment: Then there's [Delete Features (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000036000000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the power of the 'whereclause', ensuring you have all the rows you want to delete before proceeding:

```
qFlt = "SR_SN_2 <> ' ' AND SR_COLOR_2 <> ' ' AND SR_SIZE_2 <> ' ' AND SR_LOCATION2 <> ' '"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(aContainerFC2,where_clause=qFlt) as uCur:
    for dRow in uCur:
        uCur.deleteRow ()
```

by the time you get to a row object you will know that it's suitable to be deleted... using the [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) in a with block is prefereable because you don't need to `del updCurs` when you're done to release the locks.

Comment: Don't forget to include the (required) "field_names" keyword, otherwise this works.